# Issue with ViewPager inside Fragment and ActionBar (API level 16 Only)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-actionbar

Issue that I have found reproduce only on devices and emulators with API level 16 (4.1.2) + support library v4.

There is quite complicated structure: ActionBarActivity->Fragment(Outer)->ViewPager->Fragment(Inner, several instances).Each fragment inside ViewPager (Inner Fragments) changes ActionBar title and adds its own MenuItems. After replacing Outer fragment (that owns ViewPager) with another one (the same class: Outer) MenuItems (that first Inner fragment has added) become invisible and title trimmed(view that contain title do not re-sized). After swiping to the second Inner fragment and back everything return in proper state.

```
package com.bug.in.fragment.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static String[] titles = {"[*****]", "[**********]", "[***************]",};
    static int titleIndex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new Outer()).commit();
        }
    }

    private void changeOuterFragment() {
        titleIndex++;
        if (titleIndex > 2) {
            titleIndex = 0;
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Outer()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.add("A");
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;
    }

    public static class Outer extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_outer, container, false);

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return new Inner();
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return 3;
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            MenuItem item = menu.add("O.F");
            MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
    }

    public static class Inner extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titles[titleIndex]);
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_inner, container, false);

            v.findViewById(android.R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeOuterFragment();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            MenuItem item = menu.add("I.F");
            MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
}
```

I created simple project that illustrated this issue:
https://github.com/yatsevskiy/bug_in_fragment.git

Comment: any solution for this